# Sencha Touch 2 Standard Themes?

Tags: themes, sencha-touch-2

I noticed that the theme code is missing from the KitchenSink in the final version of ST2.  Are there any default themes that ship with the product?  Also, are there any open source themes available?  I'd like to have a few themes handy for demos so I can easily switch between them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there are, if you open up senchatouch2/resources/css you've got the default sencha-touch.css and then you have apple.css, android.css, bb6.css(blackberry).

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="senchatouch2/resources/css/apple.css" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think following url will help someone

http://developerextensions.com/index.php/sencha-touch-2-themes-builder

---

---Add the following link to your sencha-touch-2 app's html file.

---DEShowThemeBuilder(true); //function to show the theme builder

---DEShowThemeBuilder(false); //function to hide the theme builder

---

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://developerextensions.com/components/com_extensiondemo/views/extensiondemo/tmpl/sencha2/ux/themeBuilder/themeBuilder.js"></script>
```